# Opening file explorer on click of icon

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5 with Typescript. I need to open the file explorer window to add an attachment on clicking an icon. Now, i know how to do this for a button but somehow it does not seem to be working for icon, maybe the click event binding is not working. A little help please?

```
<input type="file" #file (change)="upload()"/>
<span class="icon-doc" (click)="file.click()">
</span>
```

And in my component :

```
upload(){
    //The functionality to upload file(s)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly your code is written, but you will need to bind that icon to a click method, which will actually programatically click the other `input` element that handles the attaching of files. This is one way you can do it:

```
<a (click)="handleClick()" href="javascript:undefined">
  <i class="la la-upload"></i>
</a>

<input class="hidden" type="file" id="upload-file" name="upload-file" accept=".csv" ngf-max-size="2MB" (change)="addAttachment($event)">
```

You will probably want to hide the input button using CSS:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

And on your component.ts,

```
handleClick() {
  document.getElementById('upload-file').click();
}

addAttachment(fileInput: any) {
  const fileReaded = fileInput.target.files[0];
  //  handle the rest 
}
```

Comment: I think i am trying the same. Let me check for any changes. I was not using a custom hidden class as well. Let me try if that helps

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I basically combined my method with yours and added the custom hidden class. Worked like a gem. Though can you explain why simply adding the hidden attribute didn't work for me?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I basically combined my method with yours and added the custom hidden class. Worked like a gem. Though can you explain why simply adding the hidden attribute didn't work for me?

Comment: @Mark glad to help! Good question there. The hidden attribute is actually similar to using `display:none`. The hidden attribute actually prevents it from being rendered on the DOM, whereas `visibility:hidden` merely makes it 'invisible'.