# How to preview an image uploaded on click of an icon (eg: attachment icon) in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

1. User click an attachment icon (input type tag would be hidden)
2. User selects an image
3. Selected image previews on an image tag

What is the best way to acheive this in Svelte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hide the input.
2. When click on upload icon trigger click on input on:click={()=>{fileinput.click();}}

pls check this repl https://svelte.dev/repl/b17c13d4f1bb40799ccf09e0841ddd90?version=3.29.0

```
    <script>
    let  avatar, fileinput;
    const onFileSelected =(event)=>{
            let image = event.target.files[0];
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            reader.onload = e => {
                 avatar = e.target.result
            };
          }
    
    </script>
 <div id="app">
 <h1>Upload Image</h1>
  
        {#if avatar}
        <img class="avatar" src="{avatar}" alt="d" />
        {:else}
        <img class="avatar" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-512.png" alt="" /> 
        {/if}
 
<img class="upload" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/625182-200.png" alt="" on:click={()=>{fileinput.click();}} />
<div class="chan" on:click={()=>{fileinput.click();}}>Change Avatar</div>
<input style="display:none" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" on:change={(e)=>onFileSelected(e)} bind:this={fileinput} >

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really different from doing it without svelte. You create a data URL from the selected file and set that as image source.

```
<script>
  let src = '';

  function onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        src = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="file" on:change={onChange} />
{#if src}
  <img {src} />
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But let's say I want to invoke the file upload on click on another custom button/image and not the input tag. How would I achieve that?

Comment: See the other answer or https://stackoverflow.com/q/57036881/218196

Comment: nevermind, got it! I attached an on:change to the original tag which runs a function that displays the image!